# VBA disable/enable shortcut key combinations

Tags: vba, ms-word, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to enable and disable the shortcut key for select all "Ctrl + A".

```
FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyA)).Disable

FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyA)).Rebind wdKeyCategoryCommand, ??
```

What is the command parameter for Ctrl + A??

I cannot find this information anywhere!

Also I want to apply it only for my templates:

```
CustomizationContext = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
```

This doesn't seem to work. it seems to apply to the normal template because if I open any word instance the shortcut key is still disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Entering

```
 ?FindKey(BuildKeyCode(wdKeyControl, wdKeyA)).Command
```

in the Immediate Window of the VBA editor shows

```
 EditSelectAll
```

so I guess that is what you are looking for.

To your second question: did you check that `ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate` is not equal to `NormalTemplate` when you disabled "Ctrl + A" ?

Comment: Thanks alot! i don't know VBA and this was exactly what i was looking for.